# How to access another class function from another class (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to java and I'm currently testing it in android studio.

I'm trying to access function **showMessage()** in **TEST** class from **TEST2** class.

There is no problem if **showMessage()** function is called within the same class but the code stopped if I tried to access it from another class.

Maybe there is something wrong with my logic or syntax, but I'm not entirely sure which one is it. I already tried to search for some solution but there is no answer that I can find to help with my situation.

**Here is my TEST.java code**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TEST extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TEST2 ab;
    Button button;

    private final String text ="Testing test test test testing test";

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false) // cancel with button only
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontest);

        ab = new TEST2(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showMessage(text);
            }
        });
    }

}

class TEST2 extends View{
    public TEST t = new TEST();

    public TEST2(Context context) {
        super(context);

    //there is error if I tried this 2 line code
    //onTest();     
    //t.showMessage("TESTING FROM TEST2 CLASS");

    }

    public void onTest(){
        t.showMessage("TESTING FROM TEST2 CLASS");
    }
}
```

and this is my **activity_test.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttontest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to pas the context in parameters

Comment: Thanks! passing the context in parameters worked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onTest(){
        if (getContext() instanceof Test)
            ((Test)getContext()).showMessage("TESTING FROM TEST2 CLASS");
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution for other problem that I have and It works flawlessly. Your answer is the best answer for my main problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing parameter context

```
public void showMessage(String message, Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false) // cancel with button only
                .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alert Dialog is a UI element it will not run from another class if activity is changed. if activity is not change try this...

```
public void showMessage(final String message,final Context mContext) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelable(false) // cancel with button only
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "if activity is not change try this......" OP clearly stated that he wants to call it from another activity

Comment: @AwaisMajeed he said he is calling from another class .. anyway if it is activity then he need s to pass context..

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by " if activity is not change"? and when I tried to add the runOnUiThread I get an error for getActivity()

Comment: technically you are right......but OP is a beginner he wrote his first activity as TEST Class....so common sense

Comment: use `this` instead of `getActivity()`. I tried your code on fragment thats why  `this` or `context` is replaced by `getActivity()`

Comment: Alright I understand it now how to access other class by passing the context. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `Context` of your `TEST2` class.

```
 public void showMessage(Context context, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    .............
    ......................
 }
```

**TEST2:**

```
public TEST2(Context context) {
    super(context);

    t.showMessage(context, "TESTING FROM TEST2 CLASS");
}
```